# NameError: name 'brand' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class parts:
    B = []
    M = []
class cars(brand):
    def __init__(self):
        self.brand = brand
bmw = cars("BMW")
mercedes = cars("Mercedes")
parts.B.append(input("What parts should we install in BMW:"))
parts.M.append(input("What parts should we install in mercedes:"))
```

It should just add parts into the class parts

i tried to define the variable brand but then it says :

TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) if int

TypeError: NoneType takes no arguments if None

TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not tuple if str

Comment: Please, post full traceback you get, incl the input you try

Answer (score 0):

You are using the undefined variable `brand` as a base class for `cars` to inherit from, rather than defining `__init__` to have a parameter named `brand`.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand


bmw = Car("BMW")
mercedes = Car("Mercedes")
```

(The class name should start with a capital letter by convention, and be a singular noun, as a single instance of `Car` represents *one* car, not multiple cars.)

Unrelated, `parts` should just be a `dict`, not a class.

```
parts = {'B': [], 'M': }

...

parts['B'].append(...)
parts['M'].append(...)
```